# Keep UICollectionView position after a reload using dynamic cell's height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, scrollview

I have a vertical UICollectionView with flow layout and I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll behaviour. When the view comes near to the end, the api request 10 more registers on the server side and then I update the collection data. But when I do that my table don't keeps on the same cell I was before the reload. How can I keep the position after a reload?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == viewModel.numberOfItemsInSection - 3 {
        self.viewModel.fetchNextRepositoriesPage() { shouldUpdateData in
            self.repositoriesListView.repositoriesCollectionView.reloadData()
            self.repositoriesListView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

private func reloadCollectionData() {
    let offset = collectionView.contentOffset
    collectionView.reloadData()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    collectionView.contentOffset = offset
}
```

## EDIT:

I noticed that this problem only occurs when I use estimadedItemSize on my collectionView. When the itemSize is a constant the problem does not occur.

Comment: Your code that remembers offset looks quite ok - but what I see is the problem of calling your fetchNextRepository on scrollViewDidScroll: method - it may be called multiple times when you scroll.

Comment: I tried using collectionView willDisplay but the same problem occurs

Comment: Try set collectionView.contentOffset in func  "collectionView.performBatchUpdates" when it completed. Hope it useful to you.